# Commerce quantity limit

Tags: commerce

In Commerce Line Items quantity field which is an integer field, user can not enter more than 9999, what should i do to unlimit the field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although that limit appears sane to me, to adjust the maxlength, look at

[commerce_line_item_field_widget_form](http://api.drupalcommerce.org/api/Drupal%20Commerce/sites!all!modules!commerce!modules!line_item!commerce_line_item.module/function/commerce_line_item_field_widget_form/DC)

```
  $element['line_items'][$line_item_id]['quantity'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield', 
    '#datatype' => 'integer', 
    '#default_value' => $quantity, 
    '#size' => 4, 
    '#maxlength' => max(4, strlen($quantity)),
  );
```

You could use [hook_field_widget_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_widget_form_alter/7) and adjust the `#maxlength` property there.